# SetInterval in javascript displays repeatedly instead of change

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

I have made a countdown that will be displayed in the table column, but it is repeating column instead of the change in the column.

The snippet will help for better understanding the question: **(edited)**

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 29, 2019 23:56:26").getTime();
var table = document.getElementById("test");
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.timer_bg {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

</table>
```

The countdown works well, it is decreasing too, every second it is generating one more column, I don't want that.

**UPDATE**

Also how to add class `timer_bg` in that row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move row and cell creation outside the setInterval.

```
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
setInterval(...)
```

Add class to row as shown below:

```
row.className = 'timer_bg';
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to create a fixed table and just inject the changed time into a fixed element.

There is no need to create the table row and cell. You can just have it already in your original HTML.

**Update 1**

If you need really to create the element dynamically you should create this element outside of the `setInterval` function (Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50089575/2735286 ). There you can also add your class name.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 29, 2019 23:56:26").getTime();
var table = document.getElementById("targetTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

// Create a "class" attribute
var att = document.createAttribute("class");
att.value = "timer_bg";
cell1.setAttributeNode(att);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  cell1.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<table id="targetTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this method, but I am having many rows with it which will be added through javascript, that's why I have chosen that method. Thanks for the solution, I have edited the question, please have a look at it once.

Comment: @Raja I have updated the answer to comply to your requirements.

Comment: In a big problem, which answers to accept?? Both are same the difference is only one has the full working and another, codes that are changed.

Comment: @Raja You should accept the other answer. Karthik's solution is more elegant: `row.className`.